# Overwrite Specific Columns in a CSV file

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, overwrite

I have an existing .csv file - data.csv - with 2 columns of data shown below.

```
COL1           COL2
1/1/1991 00:00 65.4
1/1/1991 01:00 59.2
```

I need to use either `dlmwrite`, `csvwrite` or even `fprintf` to open this file (data.csv), KEEP the first column without deleting it, and just write a new column of data overwriting the original 2nd column in the same file.

The final result will have 2 columns of data in file data.csv: the first column of data is the original column and the 2nd column is the new overwritten data from a calculation in the main program.

Final result:

```
COL1           COL2
1/1/1991 00:00 101.4
1/1/1991 01:00 96.3
```

The row offset for writing/overwriting the 2nd column is row=1, col=1 or the 2nd row and 2nd column.

I have tried `xlswrite`, `csvwrite`, `dlmwrite`, `fprintf` with varying results.  The closest attempt was using `csvwrite` and it wrote the data in the correct row and file offset but it deleted all the original data including the 1st column of data! Here is the code part that fails to run as expected without overwriting existing data - thank you!

```
R = 1; C = 1; 
rows = 241777;
ii = 1:rows -1
% place datesall and data2 into cell array to write to file
for jj =1:2
 data(ii,jj) =csvread(strcat(dirstr,files(jj).name),R,C);         
 data2(ii,jj) = ((data(ii,jj)/100)*(1/24)*24*newTcaps(jj));
 f = strcat(dirstr2,files2(jj).name);
 %f=fopen(strcat(dirstr2,files2(jj).name),'a+');
 %dlmwrite(f, data2(ii,jj) ,'delimiter', ',', 'roffset',1,'coffset',0)
 csvwrite(f, data2(ii,jj),R,C);
 %fprintf(f,[ ' ',data2(ii,jj), '\n' ]);
end
```

Comment: If you can add the code for at least the _"closest attempt"_ you have, people may be able to help you with fixing it. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: no problem - the relevant code:

Comment: R = 1; C = 1; 
rows = 241777;
ii = 1:rows -1
% place datesall and data2 into cell array to write to file
for jj =1:2
     data(ii,jj) =csvread(strcat(dirstr,files(jj).name),R,C); %all files have the same number of rows and cols...
     data2(ii,jj) = ((data(ii,jj)/100)*(1/24)*24*newTcaps(jj));
     f = strcat(dirstr2,files2(jj).name);
     %f=fopen(strcat(dirstr2,files2(jj).name),'a+');
     %dlmwrite(f, data2(ii,jj) ,'delimiter', ',', 'roffset',1,'coffset',0)
     csvwrite(f, data2(ii,jj),R,C);
     %fprintf(f,[ ' ',data2(ii,jj), '\n' ]);
end

Comment: You also change the length of the entries. In your example `65.4` becomes `101.4` so if you try to overwrite, the character `4` would overwrite the `\n` or return/enter in your csv file. So you must read in the entire csv, change it, and write it back. Have you tried `readtable` ?

Comment: if you type `help csvread` you will see `R and C are zero-based so that R=0 and C=0 specifies the first value in the file.` you start at R=1 and C=1.